# Reading up to 8 PWM's

Tags: adc, pwm

I want to read 8 PWM inputs (standard servo PWM, 1ms to 2ms) without an input capture module (my module only has 7 channels.) Could I use a capacitor and the ADC on my MCU? Does anyone know of any successful implementation of this, or have any references for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What MCU are you on?

Where are you getting all those PWM signals from?

If it's from an RC receiver, then a much better solution would be to get at the multiplexed signal instead, see [this page](http://paparazzi.enac.fr/wiki/RC_Receivers_and_Radios#R.2FC_Receiver_Interface).

If the receiver demultiplexes using a 4017, then the different servo signals will be staggered and you can re-multiplex them, simply by OR'ing the signals using diodes and a pull-down resistor.

... bottom line is that it's much easier to decode one multiplexed signal than it is to mess about with 8 inputs.

Comment: I'm using an RC receiver. I'm using a dsPIC33F or an AVR32. Either way, the number of input capture channels seems to be limited to around 8. Some have more but are in bigger packages. Thanks for the link to PPM, but I probably won't be able to use PPM as most RC receivers don't have this available without some soldering and I'd rather people didn't have to modify their receivers.

Comment: Well, you could use 8 pins and use PCINT to trigger on changes, the signals are slow enough that it ought to work. Note a timers value when the signal goes high and note the difference when the signal goes low.

Comment: That could work, I suppose, but it wouldn't work when two servos are at the same position (simulatenous interrupts - one would fire before the other.)

Comment: When the PCIE fires you have to read the entire port and act on all pin changes that you are interested in, that will naturally handle all changes that happen at the same time, but there is a fair chance that the servo inputs will be staggered in many cases because their outputs will come out of a 4017.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the suggestion - both you and Kellenjb have the same idea.

Comment: I'm going to give the accepted answer to dren.dk, but Kellenjb has a good answer too - unfortunately I can't give both the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that you put all of the PWM lines on port B. You can then setup an interrupt that is triggered on any change on that port. (I believe port B is the correct port for dsPIC33f, not sure about AVR32 though) When ever you are interrupted you can check all of your inputs and see what has changed.

With a separate timer/counter running you can count the on time for each servo.

Comment: How does this work if multiple servos fire at the same time. Actually, it might work if you captured the timer on the event, then recorded which ones changed. Thanks. Also thanks to dren.dk for suggesting something similar.

Answer (score 2):

As a side note, I see you already accepted an answer.

You can use an RC circuit with a cutoff frequency below the frequency of your PWM to average the PWM. You need it to have a cut-off of a low enough frequency to stop you having a varying output based on the phase of the PWM going by, but you must also pick a PWM that will react to a change in duty cycle fast enough for you to see it.

I hope that makes sense. This is a very easy way to do it, and with some external comparators you could use it to easily tell if a certain threshold value is violated.